# Deleted entity appears in relatedentitylist after querying

Tags: c#, devforce

Using devforce 7.2.2 i think there is a bug in the relatedentitylist.

Scenario : I call a RPC method which load an entity including one of its relatedentitylist.
I delete one of the item of the child collection then I reload the data.
Using the default QueryStrategy, I would expect to not see the deleted entity in the relatedentitylist. But there it is and with the Deleted state.

Is this behavior expected ?

```
[AllowRpc]
public static void DoStuff(IPrincipal principal, EntityManager entityManager, params Object[] args)
{
    var id = (int)args[0];

    // Load of one EntityA and his RelatedEntityList of EntityB
    var queryEntitiesA = new EntityQuery<EntityA>().With(entityManager).Include(EntityA.EntityPropertyNames.EntitiesB);
    var entityA = queryEntitiesA.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

    // Count == 3
    var count = entityA.EntitiesB.Count(); 

    // Delete of one specific EntityB of the collection
    var entityB = queryEntitiesA.EntitiesB.FirstOrDefault(md => md.Type == 1);
    entityB.EntityFacts.Delete();

    // Now Count == 2
    count = entityA.EntitiesB.Count(); 

    // Reexcution of the query with a new condition which include the EntityA previously loaded
    var entities = queryEntitiesA.Where(p => "condition including the deleted entity").OrderBy(m => m.Date).Execute().ToList();

    // Now the collection is back with a count of 3, including the deleted EntityB. The state of the entity is Deleted
    count = entityA.EntitiesB.Count(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this behavior, given what you've shown; simple tests with Order and OrderDetail entity types, and also with m:m entities, work OK.  Do you have any other settings or code you're not showing here?  Maybe with the EntityReferenceStrategy or MergeStrategy, or calling Reload on the RelatedEntityList?